# Update or Else Insert, Multiple Rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with five columns: `uid, lead_id, form_id, field_number, value`.

I want to update `value` `WHERE` `lead_id, form_id, and field_number` exist. In my script, I do not know the id (without performing a query), however `lead_id, form_id, field_number` TOGETHER are also `unique`. Occasionally, this row will `NOT exist` and will have to be Inserted rather than Updated.

It gets further complicated because I have about 30 rows, `value` columns, I want to Update/Insert and would rather do this in one query.

**UPDATE**
Here is essentially what I am using today, but it is not updating (obviously) rows that do not exist. So if data was not initially populated, but added to the update, this data is not added to the database.

Here's what I currently have:

UPDATE someTableName
    SET value = field_number 
    WHEN field_number_value_1 THEN 'newValue1'
    WHEN field_number_value_2 THEN 'newValue2'
    WHEN field_number_value_3 THEN 'newValue3'
    END 
    WHERE form_id = 3 AND lead_id = 37 AND field_number IN field_number_value_1, field_number_value_2, field_number_value_3";

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what the problem is .. do you have any unique keys on the table?

Comment: Okay, I updated the post with what I'm currently using.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO table (uid, lead_id, form_id, field_number, value) 
VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1, 0) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = value + 1 ;
```

More info: [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: This, I don't think would work for me becuase I don't have UID without querying the database, and I need to perform multiple updates at once.